# datetime display issue from webservice

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, web-services, rest

Im having diffculty with datetime when its displayed client side from my rest web service, my client side wpf app code looks like this:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string uriGroups = "http://localhost:8000/Service/Student";
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uriGroups);

        foreach(var node in xDoc.Descendants("Student"))
        {

            GroupBox groupbox = new GroupBox();
            groupbox.Header = String.Format(node.Element("StudentID").Value);
            groupbox.Width = 100;
            groupbox.Height = 100;
            groupbox.Margin = new Thickness(2);

            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Text = String.Format(node.Element("FirstName").Value + " " + (node.Element("LastName").Value));
            textBlock.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

            TextBlock textBlock1 = new TextBlock();
            textBlock1.Text = String.Format(node.Element("TimeAdded").Value);
            textBlock1.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            textBlock1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;

            StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
            stackPanel.Children.Add(groupbox);

            stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
            stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock1);
            stackPanel.Margin = new Thickness(10);

            MainArea.Children.Add(stackPanel);
        }

    }
```

And my service looks like this:

```
public class Student
{
    ....
            public DateTime TimeAdded;
        public string TimeAddedString
        {
            get
            {
                return this.TimeAdded.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            }
        }
```

But the output looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way on my client side app code to truncate this or reformat it?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, there is a tag for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast it to a DateTime and then use [String.Format](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Here is an example with one format you could use:

```
String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", ((DateTime)node.Element("TimeAdded").Value))
```

You can also use [DateTime.ToString(FORMAT)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)

```
((DateTime)node.Element("TimeAdded").Value).ToString("d");
```

I have made an assumption that .Value returns an `object`, but if it returns a DateTime then you can drop the casts.

If you are getting a string into your client, then you will need to use [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

```
(DateTime.Parse(node.Element("TimeAdded").Value)).ToString("d");
String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", DateTime.Parse(node.Element("TimeAdded").Value))
```

Comment: Cannot convert type string to system.datetime? I thought that would have did it...

Comment: @Garrith Try this where the datetime is (keep the format): DateTime.Parse(node.Element("TimeAdded").Value)   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx   I will update my answer

Comment: @Garrith Check my new updates. It sounds like you converted, but need to put it all together

Comment: Why such the hassle tho just to get a formatted datetime, why would anyone want milliseconds to the nth position?

Comment: @Garrith What if you were writing an app that is used in scientific experiments where that matters.

Comment: Then you would formatt for that not the other way around when this way is far more common ;)

Comment: @Garrith Ahhh, you mean the default output. Well, you were getting back a string (by your original unable to cast), so that might have been more the problem /shrug. I am not sure what DateTime's default .ToString returns

Answer (score 2):

You are using TimeAdded...but I think you should be using TimeAddedString

```
textBlock1.Text = String.Format(node.Element("TimeAdded").Value);
```

Should be

```
textBlock1.Text = String.Format(node.Element("TimeAddedString").Value);
```

I believe

Comment: Do you see where I was going with this? You have TimeAdded as a Date...and that's what you appear to be using in the textBlock1.Text...you may need to modify your service so that TimeAddedString is visible (which I assumed it would be because it's Public).

Comment: TimeAddedString was just to return the date in a proper format it didnt work tho. So I am onto new suggestions.

Comment: For instance `student.TimeAdded = DateTime.Now;` and then I add the rest of the student details and it should show when that student was first created

Comment: It was suppose to then send the corrected datetime format over the wire but it didnt. It comes out like it does above, even if I get rid of the timeaddedstring and just have datetime timeadded same issue some horrible formatting. So like Justin is trying to do would be the better method.